# Getting an error on java build path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting an error in eclipse "configure build path" for maven libraries which I have imported from maven.

[image]

And after cleaning the .M2 repositories of all libraries, updating the project, mvn installing and any thing else I could think of I still get these errors:

1 - Configure build path
2 -  No class exist eclipse keeps sugesting that I use another annotation for EnableWebSecurity even tough its in the the  build path...

Please help

Comment: have you configured maven to external maven or internal eclipse maven? In eclipse

Comment: @MuhammadAhmed negative. Just using sttandard maven eclipse

Comment: Download external maven and configured it to windows and use it in eclipse.

Comment: Still didnt work :'(

Comment: The log says you have not set the Java version in your POM which means Java 5, but Java 7 or higher is required by Maven. So add something like the following to your POM: `<properties><maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target></properties>`.

Comment: yup that fixed it.

Comment: @howlger please input your answer below so i can vote your answer as the correct and give you points.

Comment: Great that it works now. I'm fine with your self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There where two issues

1 -  As stated by @howlger I needed into insert maven compiler for version 11 of java...

```
<properties><maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target></properties>
```

2-  Wrong dependency, I was using a diferent version for dependency. I used spring-core-security and needed to use spring-security-web-core

Thank you @howlger